# i want to treat "&" as a normal character in AT&T

Tags: latex, newline

```
\begin{tabular}{p{11em} p{1em} p{43em}}
\skills{Tools and Languages} & &  C++, Python, Assembly X86 AT&T, Visual Studio \\
\skills{Quantitative Research} & &  Mathematical optimization, Mathematical Modeling, R, MySQL \\
\skills{Communication} & &          English, Cantonese (fluent speaker), Chinese (reading and writing)
\end{tabular}
```

the result is splitting AT and on the next row T

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the special character with a backslash before the `&`: `AT\&T`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\skills}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{11em} p{1em} p{43em}}
\skills{Tools and Languages} & &  C++, Python, Assembly X86 AT\&T, Visual Studio \\
\skills{Quantitative Research} & &  Mathematical optimization, Mathematical Modeling, R, MySQL \\
\skills{Communication} & &          English, Cantonese (fluent speaker), Chinese (reading and writing)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(unfortunately you only posted a code fragment, so I had to invent some definition for your mysterious `\skills` macro...)